# Why is fortran exe unable to find text file when called by python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, fortran, gfortran

Windows 10, GFortran, Python 3.4

I am creating a python executable (a GUI), which will call several fortran executables. The fortran executables call a text file, `keyline.txt`, created by the python executable. The fortran executables and the text file are in a subfolder labeled `F77_EXE`.

When called from the command console, the fortran executable reads `keyline.txt` without error. However, when called by python, the fortran code cannot find the text file.

I have found that if I write the fortran executables as though they are in the same folder as the python executable, they run correctly. To be clear, rather than `flnm = 'keyline.txt'`, `inquire(file=TRIM(flnm),EXIST=exists)` (the fortran executable and `keyline.txt` are in the same subfolder) I write `flnm = 'F77_EXE/keyline.txt'`, as though the executable is a folder up (with the python code).

**Question**: Why do the fortran executables behave this way? Is the python code temporarily moving the executables?

The Python call

```
subprocess.call(os.path.join(floc+'F77_EXE', 'TIMESTAMP.exe'), shell=True)
```

where `floc` is the location of the python executable, `F77_EXE` is the subfolder containing the fortran executables and text file, and `TIMESTAMP.exe` is the fortran executable to be called.

Comment: Take more care about using relevant tags which are actually followed by decent number of followers. Compare the number of followers of [tag:python-3.x] to [tag:python] and [tag:gfortran] to [tag:fortran].

Comment: Python can be started from any working directory. If your Fortran program expects the file to exist in its working directory, then you have to start it with an explicit working directory using the `cwd` argument, e.g. `f77_exe = os.path.join(floc, 'F77_EXE');` `subprocess.call(os.path.join(f77_exe, 'TIMESTAMP.exe'), cwd=f77_exe)`.